# Playing corresponding videos to different links in HTML5 Video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am using HTML5 video tag to play videos on my website. When a certain image is clicked I want it to pull up the videoplayer and play the corresponding video. Any ideas on how to do this and make it compatible across all browsers?

Heres the video player, So I want the src to change depending on what image is clicked

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="" class="videoPlayer">
<source src="" class="videoPlayer">
</video>
```

With this being the images clicked

```
<img src="images/1.jpg" class="boxImage" data-project="Project"   
data-videos="images/Portfolio/Test.webm, images/Portfolio/Test.mp4">

<img src="images/2.jpg" class="boxImage" data-project="Project"   
data-videos="images/Portfolio/Test2.webm, images/Portfolio/Test2.mp4">
```

Comment: I think your question is too broad. You can obviously use JavaScript to get this done. Give it a try and see what you can come up with. If you have specific issues with it than feel free to come for help, but you shouldn't ask us to just write everything for you. You don't learn that way.

Comment: Ive exhausted all the ways I could think of thats why I am asking.

Comment: You say you've exhausted them, so does that mean you've written some code? Please post that and we'll help figure out your issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var video = document.querySelector('video');

video.oncanplaythrough = function() {
  video.play();
};

$('.boxImage').on('click', function() {
  var data_videos = $(this).data('videos').split(',');
  for (var i = 0, l = data_videos.length; i < l; i++) {
    var mime_type = 'video/' + data_videos[i].split('.').pop();
    if ( video.canPlayType(mime_type) ) {
      video.src = data_videos[i];
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jdSja/1/)